# LibXML: After Changing a node's text content to null, like to return abbreviated node

Tags: perl, libxml2

After I set a node that original contained some data value, I'd like for this node with an empty/null text value to be in the abbreviated form:

With text:

```
<frog>green</frog>
```

Abbreviated form:

```
<frog/>
```

Current code:

```
 foreach my $child ($node->getChildnodes())
    {
     if ($child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE)
     {
      my $data = $child->getData();
      $data =~ s/(?$case_flag)$sv/$rv/g;
      $child->setData ($data);
      #my $xyz = $parser->parse_balanced_chunk ($node->toString(0))->toString(0);
     }
    }
```

The commented-out line returns what I want, but I can't get this back into the document with the abbreviated tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An abbreviated tag (e.g. `<frog/>`) is one possible representation of an element with no children except attributes. It's completely equivalent to its unabbreviated form (`<frog></frog>`). Just like you want, XML::LibXML will use the abbreviated form when possible.

```
$ perl -MXML::LibXML -e'
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->new()->parse_string("<root><foo></foo></root>");
   print $doc->toString();
'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><foo/></root>
```

"When possible" means when the element has no children except attributes, meaning when `$node->childNodes()` returns nothing.

But in your case, the element still has a child node: A text node with a empty string for value. This prevents XML::LibXML from abbreviating the element. It's up to you to delete the text node if it's empty if you want XML::LibXML to abbreviate the element. Fix:

```
for my $child ($node->getChildnodes()) {
    if ($child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        my $data = $child->getData();
        $data =~ s/(?$case_flag)$sv/$rv/g;
        if ($data eq "") {
            $node->removeChild($child);
        } else {
            $child->setData($data);
        }
    }
}
```

---

What follows is the code I use for testing.

What you are doing now:

```
$ perl -MXML::LibXML -e'
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->new()->parse_string("<root><foo> </foo></root>");
   for my $node ($doc->findnodes("//foo")) {
      $_->setData("") for $node->childNodes();
   }
   print $doc->toString();
'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><foo></foo></root>
```

The fix:

```
$ perl -MXML::LibXML -e'
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->new()->parse_string("<root><foo> </foo></root>");
   for my $node ($doc->findnodes("//foo")) {
      $node->removeChild($_) for $node->childNodes();
   }
   print $doc->toString();
'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><foo/></root>
```

Comment: Guys, I appreciate your discussion, really pretty cool to listen to.  Ikegmi I fully understand your solution of testing the value and removing the child node if value is null/empty - I will give that a try.  But  what I find strange is if I save that unabbreviated tag with the null value, then run my code again for some other change (i don't touch the same tag in question), that very same unabbreviated tag with the empty value becomes abbreviated.  Anotherwords, when i initially load the same file, all the other null text tags become abreviated when I save off the xml file as I would expect.

Comment: Is because of the setData cmd?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but perhaps this will answer it: XML::LibXML doesn't care what form was used for the element in the input XML; it probably doesn't keep track of whether the tags were originally abbreviated or not. It simply chooses the form to output based on whether the element has children or not.

Comment: If you're asking why the commented out line "works", it's because the element with the empty text serializes to `<frog></frog>`, which gets parsed into an element with no children, which gets serializes as `<frog/>`.

Comment: Sorry, what I was trying to point out is that after setData applies a null value (due to the search & replace), and then I later save-off this change back to the file ($dom->toString(1)), it saves the tag in unabreviated format.  But, when I then subsequently access the same xml file, that particular tag (with a null child text node) is then printed-out in abbreviated format.  So it recognizes the fact the tag has a null text node when I re-open the file, but it's not recognizing this fact when I create the null node - it doesn't seem to be coinsistent.

Comment: An empty text node serializes to the same as no node at all. The serialization is (acceptably) lossy, which is why you get different results. You're describing the same process as the one performed by the commented out line, so see my previous comment for the details.

Answer (score 1):

An abbreviated tag (e.g. `<frog/>`) is one possible representation of an element with no children except attributes. It's completely equivalent to its unabbreviated form (`<frog></frog>`). You can control some of the parser's output through options passed to the constructor — e.g. you can tell parser to remove empty nodes through 'no_blanks' option — but there are no options to cause XML::LibXML to output abbreviated tags when it could.

What you can do though is to apply a regular expression after serializing the XML document:

```
xyz =~ s{<\s*([^>]+)\s*>\s*</\s*\1\s*>}{<$1/>}g;
```